# How to auth to Azure Cosmos DB MongoDB API account using identity?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I was using MongoDB.Driver library (ver 2.19.0) to read/write documents from/to my Cosmos DB MongoDB API account via connection string which stored in KV.

Now I want to use identity instead of connection string for authentication, but don't know how to do it. I also asked ChatGPT, but did not get a workable sample.

I know one approach is to use MSI to retrieve Cosmos DB connection string, and then connect to DB using connection string, but this is not what I want.

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: This is not yet supported service-side. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb/feature-support-42#user-and-role-management.

Comment: So that mean, the only approach is to retrieve key using MSI and then build the connection string to connect?

Comment: There may be others. The one you suggest is here. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/store-credentials-key-vault But could possibly take a look and see if this might be possible other ways. This article here may have a solution, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-restrict-user-data