How to authenticate to Azure Cosmos DB MongoDB account using Managed identity?
I was using the MongoDB.Driver library (ver 2.19.0) to read/write documents from/to my Cosmos DB MongoDB API account via a connection string that was stored in KeyVault.
Now I want to use managed identity instead of connection string for authentication, but we have tried multiple ways to authenticate using managed identity but it has not succeeded.
Can anyone help whether we can use managed identity for Azure Cosmos for the MongoDB account?
Tried managed identity in C# code.

This is the exact same question as this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75941403/how-to-auth-to-azure-cosmos-db-mongodb-api-account-using-identity and this still has the same answer. Not possible as of right now.  If you can switch to NoSQL APi instead this is possible however you might need to re-write your data access layer for that.

According to this

Currently Cosmos DB for Mongo DB(Both vCore and RU mode) do not support Managed Identity authentication.

Alternatively, while you can't directly use MSI with Cosmos DB MongoDB API, you can still use Managed Identity to securely retrieve the connection string from Azure Key Vault. This way, your application doesn't need to store credentials and can leverage MSI for Key Vault access.
Give required permissions to the managed identity to access keys from key vault, you can use below code:
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets;
using MongoDB.Driver;

public class CosmosDBMongoService
{
    private readonly IMongoDatabase _database;

    public CosmosDBMongoService(string keyVaultUrl, string keyVaultSecretName, string dbName)
    {
        // Set up Azure Key Vault Client using Managed Identity
        var client = new SecretClient(new Uri(keyVaultUrl), new DefaultAzureCredential());
        
        // Retrieve the connection string stored as a secret in Key Vault
        KeyVaultSecret secret = client.GetSecret(keyVaultSecretName);
        string connectionString = secret.Value;

        // Use the connection string to connect to Cosmos DB MongoDB API
        var mongoClient = new MongoClient(connectionString);
        _database = mongoClient.GetDatabase(dbName);
    }

    public IMongoCollection<T> GetCollection<T>(string collectionName)
    {
        return _database.GetCollection<T>(collectionName);
    }
}

For more information you refer to the similar question in SO.
